# Calculating time difference between two dates using linux

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk

I have two text files named as `a.txt` and `b.txt`, that contain data in the following format as depicted below

```
year mn dt hr:mn:sec
xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxxxxx
```

My a.txt file is

```
2019-01-01 00:58:49.925000
2019-01-01 01:48:39.665000


2019-01-01 15:42:18.955000

2019-01-01 18:40:49.915000
2019-01-01 18:47:00.735000

2019-01-01 21:07:49.255000
2019-01-01 21:52:29.055000
2019-01-02 03:19:54.955000
2019-01-02 07:41:27.845000
2019-01-02 18:52:32.995000
```

And b.txt file contains

```
2019-01-01 00:58:50.565000
2019-01-01 01:48:39.915000
2019-01-01 04:09:53.705000
2019-01-01 06:28:07.515000

2019-01-01 15:43:13.455000
2019-01-01 18:40:53.255000
2019-01-01 18:47:04.005000
2019-01-01 18:47:03.975000
2019-01-01 21:07:53.725000
2019-01-01 21:52:37.195000

2019-01-02 07:41:34.255000
2019-01-02 19:41:08.865000
```

Additionally, each of the text files (a.txt and b.txt) contain 14 number of rows including the space.

Now I want to calculate the time difference between each row (`a.txt-b.txt`) in seconds and i want to  append the rows to a new text file c.txt which should only contain rows with time difference is between 3 to 18 second.

I did something like as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=`cat a.txt`
b=`cat b.txt`
awk '{print $a-$b}'
```

Comment: What should happen if one of the dates is empty? For instance, in the third line of your example files.

Comment: What about the blank lines? How do you want to differentiate them? `a.txt` has 10 dates whereas `b.txt` has 12 dates.

Comment: if empty results should be zero

Comment: What do mean by ***empty results***? blank lines? Assumes the dates for blank lines as 0? Or simply return 0?

Comment: yes..i assume for blank lines as zero, as rows value doesnot present its results should be zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each date to unix time using `date -d "2019-01-01 …" +%s`. Then subtract the unix times. This considers only whole seconds. Your dates include fractions of seconds. If you want to use the fractions too, change `+%s` to `+%s.%N`.

The following script includes all of your extra requirements, see the comment section of this answer.

```
paste a.txt b.txt |
awk '
function inSecs(date) {
  cmd = "date -d \""date"\" +%s"
  cmd | getline unixTime
  close(cmd)
  return unixTime
}
{
  if (NF == 4) {
    diff = inSecs($1" "$2) - inSecs($3" "$4)
    if (3 <= diff && diff <= 18)
      print $1 " " diff "sec"
  } 
}'
```

Comment: but some times in a.txt row missed whereas in b.txt row present in that case i want output to be zero...can you please modify your script once..

Comment: However, i need date to be appended in yyyy-mn-day format before the results i mean results should be something like  2019-01-01   1sec

Comment: @dtutub If you ask a question, please make it complete instead of adding new things to it after every answer. That being said, I don't understand your expected output format. If you subtracted the two dates `2019-01-02 03:04:05.0` and `2019-01-01 01:01:01.0` then what would be the expected output?

Comment: please update sir answer as i need date also. i did something like print  date inSecs($1)-inSecs($2) ...it doesnot give results as i wish

Comment: i think in my case dates are similar only time changes

Comment: Change `print inSecs($1)-inSecs($2)` to `print "2019-01-01 " (print inSecs($1)-inSecs($2)) "sec"` as a quick hack. I won't update the answer since I only want to give correct answers, but you could not really specify what "correct" is.

Comment: its for 2019-01-01 but in my data set 2019-02-xx also there,is it possible to write every time print " 2019-01-01" instead i need something automatic process

Comment: Then please specify which date to use. E.g. the one from `a.txt`.

Comment: if you can  help little more, actually i need to keep only seconds which falls in between 3 and 18 seconds...if possible

Comment: Done. But if you ever ask a question again, please make it complete from the very beginning. Or even better, put in some effort yourself. Writing one additional `if` for your newest requirement shouldn't  be that hard.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for [mktime()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) based on one possible interpretation of your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
!NF { next }
{ gsub(/[-:]/," ") }
NR==FNR {
    file1[NR] = $0
    next
}
FNR in file1 {
    diff = mktime($0) - mktime(file1[FNR])
    if ( (3 <= diff) && (diff <= 18) ) {
        print diff
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk a.txt b.txt
4
4
4
8
7
```

Obviously just add `> c.txt` to redirect the output.

If that's not what you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide the expected output given your posted sample input.