# Different script behavior between Ubuntu 20.04.2 and 21.04 terminated

Tags: linux, shell, awk, ubuntu-20.04

Can run the below command in shell script with no problem on Ubuntu 21.04 :

```
grep -h "new tip" logs/node.log | tail -1000 | sed -rn "s/\[(.*)\].\[(.*)\].* ([0-9]+)/\2,\3/p" | awk -F, -v threshold=2 '{"date +%s.%3N -d\""$1"\""|getline actualTime; delay=actualTime-$2-1591566291; sum+=delay; if (delay > threshold ) print $1 " " delay;} END {print "AVG=", sum/NR}'
```

but when I run the exact same script on Ubuntu 20.04.2, I get this error :

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

It's definitely the exact same script because I scp'd it from the 21.04 to 20.04.2.  Couldn't find any topics in stackoverflow or on the overall internet which addressed this difference.  Both Ubuntu's are on Linux cloud servers. About the only way to run the script with no error is taking out this `awk` line: `"date +%s.%3N -d\""$1"\""|getline actualTime`;

I tried playing around with the reference to the `$1` field but nothing would work. Tried it with `nawk` instead of `awk`, but no luck. Maybe as a last resort I can upgrade the OS from v 20 to v 21.

Has anyone seen this before?

Added: Thanks all for the quick replies. Here are the first lines of the log file that the script is running against

[Relaynod:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:60] [2021-06-30 02:20:14.36 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: de56b9f458e8942ca74c6a1913dc58fa896823dc19b366285e15481f434ed337 at slot 33453323
[Relaynod:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:60] [2021-06-30 02:20:15.17 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: e88ea4f438944bd15186fe93f321c117ec769cfbd33667654634f4510cfd3780 at slot 33453324

Just to make sure it's not a data issue. I ran the script on the Ubuntu 21 server against the file (worked), then copied the file to the Ubuntu 20 server and ran the exact same script against the copied file, and get the error.

I'll try out the suggestions on this topic and will let everyone know the answer.

New update: after laptop crash and replacement, remembered to come back to this post. I ended up using mktime like Ed mentioned. It's working now.

The shell script:

#!/bin/bash
grep -h "new tip" logs/node.log | tail -1000 | sed -rn "s/[(.*)].[(.*)].* ([0-9]+)/\2,\3/p" | mawk -F, -v threshold=2 -f check_delay.awk

The awk script:

```
BEGIN{ ENVIRON["TZ"] = "UTC"; }
{
  year = substr($1,1,4);
  month = substr($1,6,2);
  day = substr($1,9,2);
  hour = substr($1,12,2);
  min = substr($1,15,2);
  sec = substr($1,18,2);
  timestamp = year" "month" "day" "hour" "min" "sec;
  actualTime=mktime(timestamp) + 7200;
        delay=actualTime-$2-1591566291;
        sum+=delay;
        if (delay >= threshold )
                print $1 " " delay;}
END {print "AVG=", sum/NR}
```

Comment: Some sample data that you get the error with would be useful.

Comment: @Cardsfan: The OS version certainly does not matter.  The shell version may make a difference, though I don't see any syntax problem here too .... Also POSIX shells versions don't evolve so quickly. I would calculate the SHA or MD5 on both sides and compare them.

Comment: You don't need sed when you're using awk, and you don't need to spawn a subshell to call date when you have GNU awk (as you do since you are using GNU sed). If you post a new question with it's own [mcve] including sample contents of logs/node.log and the expected output then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: No repro on Ubuntu 20.04 fresh Docker image. Voting to close as lacking debugging details. If you want to pursue this further, probably try to pare down the problematic script to a simpler one; see also the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

You're spawning a shell to call `date` using whatever value happens to be in `$1` in your data so the result of that will depend on your data. Look:

```
$ echo '3/27/2021' | awk '{"date +%s.%3N -d\""$1"\"" | getline; print}'
1616821200.000

$ echo 'a"b' | awk '{"date +%s.%3N -d\""$1"\"" | getline; print}'
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
a"b
```

and what this command outputs from a log file:

```
sed -rn "s/\[(.*)\].\[(.*)\].* ([0-9]+)/\2,\3/p"
```

will vary greatly depending on the contents of specific lines in the log file since the parts you're trying to isolate aren't anchored and use `.*`s when you presumably meant to use `[^]]*`s. For example:

```
$ echo '[foo] [3/27/2021] 15 something [probably] happened at line 50'
[foo] [3/27/2021] 15 something [probably] happened at line 50

$ echo '[foo] [3/27/2021] 15 something [probably] happened at line 50' |  sed -rn "s/\[(.*)\].\[(.*)\].* ([0-9]+)/\2,\3/p"
3/27/2021] 15 something [probably,50

$ echo '[foo] [3/27/2021] 15 something [probably] happened at line 50' |  sed -rn "s/\[(.*)\].\[(.*)\].* ([0-9]+)/\2,\3/p" | awk -F, -v threshold=2 '{"date +%s.%3N -d\""$1"\""|getline actualTime; delay=actualTime-$2-1591566291; sum+=delay; if (delay > threshold ) print $1 " " delay;} END {print "AVG=", sum/NR}'
date: invalid date ‘3/27/2021] 15 something [probably’
AVG= -1591566341
```

If you want to do that then you could introduce a check for a valid date to avoid THAT specific error, e.g. (but obviously create a better date verification regexp than this):

```
$ echo 'a"b' | awk '$1 ~ "[0-9]/[0-9]+/[0-9]" {"date +%s.%3N -d\""$1"\"" | getline; print}'
$
```

but it's still fragile and extremely slow.

You're using GNU sed for `-r` so you have or can get GNU awk and that has builtin time functions so you shouldn't be spawning a subshell to call date in the first place, you should just be using `mktime()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68180908/1745001, which will avoid cryptic errors like that and run orders of magnitude faster.